# Looking for a 3.5 reference to a Monster Harvester's Handbook

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew

Back in the day, someone had created a handbook for harvesting parts from monsters. They went through every monster in the SRD and chose parts (and fairly reasonable prices for those parts). I was wondering if anyone knew of a link to the old material. I can only find links to [5e versions](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/3m4eqn/monster_harvesters_handbook_price_guide_for/), which is not what I am looking for.

I believe there were multiple versions, and the one I vaguely recollect was a Word document. I also think there was an Excel version, IIRC, I was not as fond of that one (I do not recall why, as this was many years ago).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not exactly the specific source you described, there are a number of sources for 3.x that reference monster parts:

Official sources:

- http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/magic/metamagicComponents.htm
- Complete Mage has some optional material spell components, as does a few other source books which shall not be named (by me).
- Player's Handbook II has the Trophy Collector feat.
- some 3rd edition Dragon era articles also have monster parts (317 among others)
- Unearthed Arcana has a small section about monster parts
- Draconomicon has some dragon related ones

Also, previous editions of the game were a little more forthcoming with this sort of information... check out this old thread: https://www.enworld.org/threads/critter-bits-and-magic-recipes.35574/
It mentions...:

- various old Dragon "Ecology of the..." magazine articles (use the [DragonDex](http://aeolia.net/dragondex/index.html) to search for them)
- ye olde Monstrous Manual has a bunch scattered in the monster descriptions
- The 1e DMG, p116-7 has a list of ingredients for potions. Also look for "Power Components"
- Dragon 137 has a list of values for hides and body parts, young creatures and eggs.
- Monstrous Compendium Annuals have more parts listed in monster descriptions
- and more....

Lastly, there are alternate sources:

- 101 Arcane/Divine Spell Components books from 2003 which is OGL material.
- White Dwarf magazine (issues 59-63) Graeme Davis articles had detailed monster parts magic item creation rules for most of the items in the original Dungeon Masters Guide

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! I assumed it was a longshot that I would find the exact Word document that I saw twelve plus years ago, but this response is amazing! I was not fond of the 5e material because it was unbalanced and would be too difficult to convert to 3.5. But, this is more than enough content that I think I could work with. Thank you very much! I will leave this open a little while longer in case anyone does happen to find the specific document, but in a day or two, I'll mark this as the answer if no one does.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe You are most welcome!